# Can Ubuntu One Music Store be used offline?

Tags: ubuntu-one, offline

I have a Zune HD and want to be able to listen to music without an internet connection.  Would this be possible?  Could I download the music to my computer and then put it on my Zune for the 3.99$ or 39.99$ a year subscription to Ubuntu One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. Music purchased from the music store is sent directly to your personal cloud; you can then sync the Purchased Music folder to your computer using the Ubuntu One control panel, and then all that purchased music is on your PC and you can copy it to your Zune however you like.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Looks like I'm getting me a subscription!